# Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Am trying to send message from a website to my chrome extension. Am getting above error. Any good hopes?

```
I have added my website URL in 

manifest.json: 

"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "https://www.mywebsite.com/*"
    ]
}

background.js:

//My Listener
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
   console.log('::::::onMessage::::::::');
   sendResponse({a : 'SuccessResponse'});
});

//From Website am sending message like below
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('my_extension_id' , { 
  action: 'my_action_name'
}, function(response) { 
  console.log('response', response); 
});
```

Comment: Rename onMessage to [onMessageExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: @wOxxOm, I tried. But it didn't worked.

Comment: @wOxxOm, also this worked on localhost, and threw above error when sending message from other website.

Comment: Reload the extension on chrome://extensions page when you edit manifest.json or background.js.

Comment: No @wOxxOm, Every time I will do this refresh. No improvement.

Comment: Add your entire manifest.json to the question or at least the part where background.js is declared.

Comment: Thanks all. the issue resolved without making any changes. May be kind of browser issue. @wOxxOm